# Upgrade from Kubuntu 21.10 to 22.04 failed

Tags: package-management, kubuntu, 21.10, 22.04

When updating, the updater crashed and now the system is semi-broken.

Now it changed the repos to the 22.04 repos but didn't update any packages.

While fixing the packages, I had to forcefully remove `neovim`.

Now, when using `apt`, it tries to call ***archive.ubuntu.com*** but it cannot be resolved.

`dpkg --configure -a` has been run successfully before removal of `neovim` but now it doesn't do anything.

What can i do — can I revert the repos and cleanup the mess?

**note: I can boot fine into KDE and use all apps (except `neovim`)**

Comment: Are you able to access the internet otherwise using google chrome? Have you tried the `curl` command to see if it resolves? Have you verified the contents of `/etc/resolv.conf`?

Comment: Usually, you would resume with `sudo apt -f install` after running `dpkg --configure -a` but, of course, that won't work if the repo won't resolve.

Comment: i will verify resolv.conf.  also dpkg cofigure all does nothing at all

Comment: Also, I was talking about  `curl archive.ubuntu.com` to see if you get a "could not resolve host" error.